# Casting Pointers to int in c

Tags: c, pointers, recursion, int

I have to learn it for my study. Is their any way to cast a pointer to integer. I have to give myEulerForward1 a pointer as a paramter and i always get this error message :

```
eulerZahl.c: In function ‘main’:
eulerZahl.c:38:35: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘myEulerForward1’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
  double forward = myEulerForward1(k);
                                   ^
eulerZahl.c:16:8: note: expected ‘int *’ but argument is of type ‘int’
 double myEulerForward1(int *n1){
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Can someone help me with it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>


double kFactorial(int k){


    if(k <= 1){
        return 1;
    }

    return k * kFactorial(k - 1);
}


double myEulerForward1(int *n1){


    double n = 1;   
    double euler, nFact = 1;
    for(int i = sizeof(&n1); i >= 0; i--){
        nFact*= i;
        euler = euler + (1.0/nFact);
    }

    return euler;

}


int main(){

    int k = 4;
    double factorial = kFactorial(k);

    printf("The factorial of %d is: %lf ", k, factorial); 

    double forward = myEulerForward1(k);

    printf("The Eulers Number: %lf", forward);
}
```

Comment: you are trying to pass an integer where a pointer is expected. try double forward = myEulerForward1(&k); or change double myEulerForward1(int *n1){ to double myEulerForward1(int n1){

Comment: `for(int i = sizeof(&n1); i >= 0; i--)`?? Asks for the size of a pointer.

Comment: In the same function `double euler` is uninitialised in the line `euler = euler + (1.0/nFact);`. Please enable and fix all compiler warnings.

Comment: Thanks dude i missed the &.

Comment: Okay now i fixed all compiler warnings and i get inf as my eulers number

Answer (score 0):

First i can see an error at `sizeof(&n1);`
Of course n1 is a pointeur. His Value is a RAM address. But for see his Deferenced value, you must use `*` before n1. `&` is used for get the adress of something. `*` is used for get the inside of a pointer.

Use : `sizeof(*n1);`

In Second, i see that you get a pointer in the prototype of *myEulerForward1*

`double myEulerForward1(int *n1)`

It's your compile error. He said that your function need a pointer (an adress) and that you put everything except that.

So when you call this function, you must put a pointer (a RAM adress).
And for do that, in the calling of the function, you must use `&` of course for get the adress of n1 and not his number value.

Use : `double forward = myEulerForward1(&k);`

Answer (score 0):

Well, yes, it is possible to convert a pointer to an `int`, and vice versa.

However, you are making a serious mistake in asking that question.   There are circumstances where converting an `int` to a pointer, or vice versa, makes sense.   But, in your code, you would be using it as a blunt instrument to force the compiler to accept bad code.

Your compiler is complaining because you have passed an `int` to a function that expects an `int *`.

Forcing the issue, by converting that `int` to a pointer, will stop the compiler complaining, but then you'll (possibly) get some form of runtime error, since the function will receive an invalid pointer.

Your choices are

- remove the `*` from `double myEulerForward1(int *n1)`.  This will mean, the function expects an `int`, so your code that passes an `int` will be correct.
- Call the function as `myEulerForward1(&k)` which passes an address of `k` (which is not `k` converted to a pointer) as a pointer.

Looking at the body of `myEulerForward1()` there are other problems as well.   You need to read up and better understand what `sizeof` does.   Whether your function accepts an `int` or a pointer (`int *`) the logic of your function is faulty.